# Large file upload to amazon s3 failing after 30 second limit set by heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, amazon-s3

I store my uploaded files in amazon s3 services with the following command

```
AWS::S3::S3Object.store(params[:uploadfile].original_filename, open(params[:uploadfile]), 'mybucket', :access => :private, :content_type => params[:uploadfile].content_type)
```

I can upload file's up to 30Mb without having a problem. I have read in other posts that this could be due to the fact the file is being loaded into memory(confused). The largest file i am going to upload is 40Mb, how can i achieve this without the upload failing.

My chrome browser returns the following error to me

```
Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): The connection was reset.
```

When i tried uploading from my development machine(localhost), i could upload large file > 80-100Mb, however its not working from heroku, i don't understand why, because i am uploading files directly to s3.

**Strangely my downloads fail after 30 seconds , which is the timeout limit that heroku sets, however i do not recieve any error of timeout or failed upload from heroku logs**

Thank you for your help

Comment: what is the timeout setting on your webserver?

Comment: @mikhailov i use heroku, and i think the timeout for any request is 37 seconds, i know this, that's why i upload directly to s3, so timeout should not be a problem with heroku, however i am not familiar with amazon s3.

Comment: is it happening on other browsers too?

Comment: @mikhailov tried firefox, safari, ie all failing, i have tried the swf-upload plugin and strangely it works, however i need my code to work without any upload plugin. thanks

Comment: are **params** the same for swf-upload and without plugin?

Comment: @mikhailov not sure about params, the code looks complex and can't seen to figure out why all the plugins i have tested works, only my code does not, connection just gets reset above 35mb.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After many months on this issue, i found a gem that works well, by uploading directly to amazon s3, without any complex flash, and javascript suff. I also integrates into carrierwave.
The gem is called [Carrierwave_direct](https://github.com/dwilkie/carrierwave_direct)

Works without a problem, however if you are using rails 3.0.x checkout this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399238/uploads-silently-failing-pausing-with-new-carrierwave-direct-gem-when-uploading-t) for a solution.

If you are using rails rails 3.1.x, you are all set to go.

Comment: In case anyone is trying to solve this and that gem doesn't quite cut it, I was able to accomplish something similar with Uploadify (uploading directly to a S3 bucket) and some simple AJAX communication between client and server. It wasn't production-ready code but it worked. You could probably get this working with just about any flash uploader.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you're not actually uploading directly to S3, but rather uploading to Heroku, which is then uploading to S3.

You should use something like https://github.com/GreenAsJade/s3-swf-upload-plugin to help you implement to help you implement true direct to S3 uploading ( http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?UsingHTTPPOST.html )

Comment: thanks for the help, i was aware of swf plugin, however i was trying to avoid embedded flash, and extra javascript. i am trying to understand how the plugins bypass heroku so that i can implement it in my app. i would have gone with swf, but i need to figure out how swf uploads directly to s3, does it establish the connection differently, whats all the stuff inside swf's s3_uploads_controller.rb . thanks again

Comment: The 2nd of those links is the AWS documentation on direct to S3 uploads.

Comment: I'm using https://github.com/nathancolgate/s3-swf-upload-plugin on rails 3 and it works great

Comment: @Jords on the s3-swf-upload-plugin, what kind of file sizes are you uploading? I had a fully functional drag/drop AJAX version uploading directly to S3 but it only worked for smaller files.  Whenever I uploaded files about 150+ MB it would get partway uploaded and just crash, usually with a response from Amazon S3 about some error. Small files were great but larger not so much. Would you mind tell me what's the largest file size you have successfully uploaded using this plugin?

Comment: Probably about 20-30mb, and I can't conceive somebody uploading a file larger than that to my site. So I can't help with issues uploading really large files - it's possible there is some issue with the flex side etc. Maybe multipart uploads would work better - but I'm not sure of something which implements that in the browser.